# how to set distinct breaks and cut data in R

Tags: r

I have dataset with an array of BMI values, say:

```
data <- c(NA, 33.95144674, NA, NA, 28.4686277, 27.05992129, 30.75396825, 
NA, 34.13580247, 29.71428571, 20.0390625, 36.39579962, 34.08660523, 
NA, 25.16069789, 33.09240363, 27.12031558, 21.00346021, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 25.71100827, 32.4213921, 25.42220947, 24.21690704)
```

I wanted to cut it into 4 categories ("<18.5", "18.5-24.99", "25-29.99", ">30") and produced the following code for chisq testing.

```
  bmidata <- data [,"bmi_0m"] 
    bmirange<-cut (bmidata, breaks=c(0,18.5,25,30,100), labels=c("<18.5", "18.5-24.99", "25-29.99", ">30"), include.lowest = TRUE)
    table (bmirange)
    prop.table(table (bmirange))
```

The problem is I don't really know where the values cut off using the breaks. Have I just cut the data as 0-18.5, 18.5-25 etc.? If so, how can I set better distinct breakpoints?

Comment: (1) *"better distinct breakpoints"* is completely contextual, I don't know what you're using it for to be able to recommend anything different from what you're using. (2) *"I don't really know where the values cut off"* is confusing to me. You have the values and you set the breaks, can you explain that statement in a different way?

Comment: @r2evans I guess I'm trying to understand my own code lol. I want to be able to group the array into brackets of "less than 18.5", "18.5-24.99", "25-29.99", "greater than 30". Mathematically it would be [0,18.5), [18.5, 25), [25-30), [30,100].

Comment: @RonakShah I want to be able to group the array into brackets of "less than 18.5", "18.5-24.99", "25-29.99", "greater than 30". Mathematically it would be [0,18.5), [18.5, 25), [25-30), [30,100]. Can I set my break as break=c(0,18.5,25,30,100), because if the value 18.5 comes up in the array would it fall into the first or second bracket or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the parameter `right` which has the description

```
logical, indicating if the intervals should be closed on the 
right (and open on the left) or vice versa.
```

So what you want is to set `right = FALSE`

```
bmirange<-cut (bmidata, 
               breaks=c(0,18.5,25,30,100), 
               labels=c("<18.5", "18.5-24.99", "25-29.99", ">30"), 
               right = FALSE,
               include.lowest = TRUE)
```